# Is there any limit on list items in Excel cell dropdown using VSTO C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am using `vsto` to create excel add-in. I am adding a validation to a cell and making it as a `Dropdown`. The data source for the dropdown is present in another column. I'm using this code.

```
string values = string.Join(",", cellValuesArray);

cellRange.Validation.Delete();
               
cellRange.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList, Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop,
                         Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, values , Type.Missing);

cellRange.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
```

Now if `cellValuesArray` contains more than 1200(approx) items then it throws an error says

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

It works fine if number of items are small like 600-700. I'm not sure how to solve this.

So how can I add the validation in such a way so that my dropdown can hold more than 1K records or probably much higher than that?

Comment: why do you want so many records in your dropdown.. have you considered doing and or taking a different approach perhaps load 100 items and from there querying the database to return records based on a LiKE clause in regards to what you type in the drop down..:

Comment: Yeah @MethodMan I agree with you but I don't have any database here. I just have an another sheet which contains the source data and based on that, I need to make sure that user can't put invalid data into my main cell. That's why I am populating the dropdown.

Comment: I also observed that its throwing this exception when `values.Length` is greater than `8190` i.e if total number of characters in the comma delimited string is more than 8190. I didn't find any information about this limit till now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research finally I found the solution. If you have large amount of data that you want to source in a dropdown in a excel cell then using a formula is a better solution than using the `List` of items.

```
string formula = "='SheetName'!$B$2:$B$" + lastRowIndex;
cellRange.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList, Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop,
                     Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, formula , Type.Missing);
```

I am using the column `B` here, you can change it accordingly.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem but my dropdown list is in Ribbon and after 7 item it dies off... Any clue of why its happening or is there some limitation. I'm loading 50 items approx